# arm neon assembly performance issue in xiaomi5s

Tags: arm, neon

Consider the following codes, The first code snippet：

```
void run_new(const float* src, float* dst,
        size_t IH, size_t IW, size_t OH, size_t OW,
        size_t N) {
    rep(n, N) {
        const float* src_ptr = src + IW * IH * n;
        float* outptr = dst;

        const float* r0 = src_ptr;
        const float* r1 = src_ptr + IW;

        float32x4_t k0123 = vdupq_n_f32(3.f);
        rep(h, OH) {
            size_t width = OW >> 2;

            asm volatile(
                    "dup v21.4s, %4.s[0] \n"
                    "dup v22.4s, %4.s[1] \n"
                    "dup v23.4s, %4.s[2] \n"
                    "dup v24.4s, %4.s[3] \n"
                    "mov x3, xzr \n"
                    "0:           \n"
                    "ldr q0, [%1] \n"
                    "ld1 {v1.4s, v2.4s}, [%2], #32 \n"

                    "add x3, x3, #0x1 \n"
                    "cmp %0, x3 \n"

                    "ld1 {v3.4s, v4.4s}, [%3], #32 \n"
                    "fmla v0.4s, v1.4s, v21.4s \n"  // src[i] * k[i]
                    "fmla v0.4s, v2.4s, v22.4s \n"

                    "fmla v0.4s, v3.4s, v23.4s \n"
                    "fmla v0.4s, v4.4s, v24.4s \n"

                    "str q0, [%1], #16 \n"
                    "bne 0b \n"
                    : "+r"(width), "+r"(outptr), "+r"(r0), "+r"(r1)
                    : "w"(k0123)
                          : "cc", "memory", "x3", "v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v21", "v22", "v23", "v24");
        }

    }
}
```

The second code snippet:

```
 void run_origin(const float* src, float* dst,
        size_t IH, size_t IW, size_t OH, size_t OW,
        size_t N) {

    rep(n, N) {
        const float* src_ptr = src + IW * IH * n;
        float* outptr = dst;

        const float* r0 = src_ptr;
        const float* r1 = src_ptr + IW;

        float32x4_t k0123 = vdupq_n_f32(3.f);
        rep(h, OH) {
            size_t width = OW >> 2;

            asm volatile(
                    "dup v21.4s, %4.s[0] \n"
                    "dup v22.4s, %4.s[1] \n"
                    "dup v23.4s, %4.s[2] \n"
                    "dup v24.4s, %4.s[3] \n"
                    "mov x3, xzr \n"
                    "mov x4, xzr \n"
                    "0:           \n"
                    "add x19, %2, x4 \n"
                    "ldr q0, [%1] \n"  // load dst 0, 1, 2, 3
                    "ld1 {v1.4s, v2.4s}, [x19]\n"  // 1, 2, 4, 6

                    "add x3, x3, #0x1 \n"
                    "cmp %0, x3 \n"

                    "add x19, %3, x4 \n"
                    "ld1 {v3.4s, v4.4s}, [x19]\n"
                    "fmla v0.4s, v1.4s, v21.4s \n"  // src[i] * k[i]
                    "fmla v0.4s, v2.4s, v22.4s \n"

                    "fmla v0.4s, v3.4s, v23.4s \n"
                    "fmla v0.4s, v4.4s, v24.4s \n"

                    "add x4, x4, #0x20 \n"
                    "str q0, [%1], #16 \n"
                    "bne 0b \n"
                    "add %2, %2, x4 \n"
                    "add %3, %3, x4 \n"
                    : "+r"(width), "+r"(outptr), "+r"(r0), "+r"(r1)
                    : "w"(k0123)
                          : "cc", "memory", "x3", "x4", "x19", "v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v21", "v22", "v23", "v24");

        }

    }
}
```

All the code in [Test performance of arm neon assembly](https://gist.github.com/sethbrin/2ec2ba9a374e7eaf003888c14b0b9219)

I test the performance of these two codes on `xiaomi5s`、`xiaomi6`、`redmi`, The detail of the performance is:

> N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112

1. perf origin: 325.35058 mflops --- new: 4275.63483 mflops --- speedup: 13.14162  **xiaomi5s**
2. perf origin: 3082.00078 mflops --- new: 3063.45047 mflops --- speedup: 0.99398 **xiaomi6**
3. perf origin: 1761.05058 mflops --- new: 1814.37185 mflops --- speedup: 1.03028 **redmi**

The following test in xiaomi5s.

> N: 12 IH:48-256 IW: 224

1. N: 12 IH: 48 IW: 224 OH: 24 OW: 112
   perf origin: 3721.16633 mflops --- new: 4935.31729 mflops --- speedup: 1.32628
2. N: 12 IH: 80 IW: 224 OH: 40 OW: 112
   perf origin: 1185.58378 mflops --- new: 3852.38266 mflops --- speedup: 3.24936
3. N: 12 IH: 112 IW: 224 OH: 56 OW: 112
   perf origin: 1021.83468 mflops --- new: 3503.70672 mflops --- speedup: 3.42884
4. N: 12 IH: 144 IW: 224 OH: 72 OW: 112
   perf origin: 797.61461 mflops --- new: 4167.12780 mflops --- speedup: 5.22449
5. N: 12 IH: 176 IW: 224 OH: 88 OW: 112
   perf origin: 465.55073 mflops --- new: 4084.54206 mflops --- speedup: 8.77357
6. N: 12 IH: 208 IW: 224 OH: 104 OW: 112
   perf origin: 373.99237 mflops --- new: 4255.78687 mflops --- speedup: 11.37934
7. N: 12 IH: 240 IW: 224 OH: 120 OW: 112
   perf origin: 341.57406 mflops --- new: 4290.58840 mflops --- speedup: 12.56122

> N: 12 IH:224 IW: 48-256

1. N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 48 OH: 112 OW: 24
   perf origin: 3660.35916 mflops --- new: 4729.61877 mflops --- speedup: 1.29212
2. N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 80 OH: 112 OW: 40
   perf origin: 2918.48755 mflops --- new: 4748.17285 mflops --- speedup: 1.62693
3. N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 112 OH: 112 OW: 56
   perf origin: 951.03852 mflops --- new: 4051.84318 mflops --- speedup: 4.26044
4. N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 144 OH: 112 OW: 72
   perf origin: 1186.74405 mflops --- new: 4160.18572 mflops --- speedup: 3.50555
5. N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 176 OH: 112 OW: 88
   perf origin: 533.47286 mflops --- new: 4199.36622 mflops --- speedup: 7.87175
6. N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 208 OH: 112 OW: 104
   perf origin: 447.30682 mflops --- new: 4092.22256 mflops --- speedup: 9.14858
7. N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 240 OH: 112 OW: 120
   perf origin: 442.58206 mflops --- new: 4200.13672 mflops --- speedup: 9.49007

> IC: 2-12 IH:224 IW: 224

1. N: 2 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 3794.45684 mflops --- new: 5236.48508 mflops --- speedup: 1.38004
2. N: 3 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 3790.20521 mflops --- new: 5150.30622 mflops --- speedup: 1.35885
3. N: 4 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 2117.55521 mflops --- new: 4329.34274 mflops --- speedup: 2.04450
4. N: 5 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 1290.43541 mflops --- new: 3915.65607 mflops --- speedup: 3.03437
5. N: 6 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 1038.86926 mflops --- new: 3747.69392 mflops --- speedup: 3.60747
6. N: 7 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 845.26878 mflops --- new: 4025.81237 mflops --- speedup: 4.76276
7. N: 8 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 658.23150 mflops --- new: 3971.62335 mflops --- speedup: 6.03378
8. N: 9 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 527.99489 mflops --- new: 4163.94501 mflops --- speedup: 7.88634
9. N: 10 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
   perf origin: 416.75353 mflops --- new: 4119.03296 mflops --- speedup: 9.88362
10. N: 11 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
    perf origin: 378.38875 mflops --- new: 4203.33717 mflops --- speedup: 11.10852
11. N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112
    perf origin: 350.36924 mflops --- new: 4202.19842 mflops --- speedup: 11.99363

I am confused by the performance test in `xiaomi5s`, Why the performance of the first code on xiaomi5s so bad.

I guess it may be caused by the pipeline of neon is broken if it wait for the normal register such as `ld1 {v3.4s, v4.4s}, [x19]` wait for `x19` which is calculated by `add x19, %3, x4`, but I am not very sure。

Addition details:

1. xiaomi5s cpu: Qualcomm Snapdragon 821
2. xiaomi6 cpu: Qualcomm Snapdragon 835
3. redmi cpu: MediaTek Helio X20

Compile options(clang version: 5.0.0): `clang++ -std=c++11 -Ofast`.

---

1. I change `ldr q0, [%2]` to `ld1 v0.4s, [%2]`, but the result is the same, the performance of the `run_origin` may be a little faster, about 1%-3%.

> N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112

perf origin: 342.96631 mflops --- asm: 4288.51646 mflops --- speedup: 12.50419

2. I change `fmla v0.4s, v1.4s, v21.4s` to `smlsl2 v0.2d, v1.4s, v21.4s`, but the result is the same.

   > N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112

perf origin: 348.03699 mflops --- asm: 4245.18804 mflops --- speedup: 12.19752

3. I change `fmla v0.4s, v1.4s, v21.4s` to `fadd v0.4s, v1.4s, v21.4s`, the origin code gets faster.

> N: 12 IH: 224 IW: 224 OH: 112 OW: 112

perf origin: 743.95433 mflops --- asm: 4756.65769 mflops --- speedup: 6.39375

Comment: Did you replace ldr with ld1? It might be really the culprit in this case. I'm really curious.

Comment: yes, I replace ldr width ld1, but the result is the same.

Comment: Then change FMLAs to integer MLAs, disregarding the results. If it gets significantly faster, it proves that the fused multiply implementation on the chip is the problem which is unsolvable.

Comment: I change `fmla v0.4s, v1.4s, v21.4s` to `smlsl2 v0.2d, v1.4s, v21.4s`, but the result is the same. so it's not the fused multiply implementation problem.

Comment: I also tried changing `fmla` to `fadd`, the origin code gets twice faster.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess is that the bottleneck is just as likely to be in the memory/cache subsystem as the core. Perhaps the first case does something that inhibits automatic pre-loading (or the xiaomi5s lacks this or has it disabled)?

It might be interesting to try adding a `pld` (or rather `prfm`) instruction, though I've never found them to help much on Cortex-A9 at least.

An easy way to check if `fmla` is the bottleneck would be to comment out some or all of the data-processing instructions (of course, the output will be wrong!)

Comment: 1. The two codes whose  access memory mode should be the same, 
I guess it wasn't caused by cache/memory.
2. I have tried prefetch, but useless. Prefetching is very unstable, sometimes performance improved, sometimes reduced.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still not as familiar with NEON64 as with NEON32, but there are several things I wouldn't do in your code:

- Why are you using the VFP instruction "ldr"?. Switching between VFP and NEON can cost lots of cycles, especially if these instructions are memory accessing ones. That both share the registers doesn't mean they are the same unit. Change it to LD1 ...... 4s
- Do you want it 32bit or 64bit? Chose x3 or w3, and stick to it.
- Are you sure you want fused multiply with fmla? Maybe yes or maybe no, but note that fused multiplies cost more...

cheers

Comment: I'm curious. Why don't you write your routines in real assembly instead of the inline one?

Comment: Because the workload is too large, the code above is only a small part.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The code above is the change that I encountered when I was optimizing convolution. The code was originally written by intrinsic, I rewrote the code compiled by the clang compiler and got the second code above.
1. because this code is modified from a code which generate by compiler, this code is changed from the compiler generated code, in order to verify this problem, I kept the code.
2. x3 is a index, i want to use 64bit, i'll modify it.
3. This code has been modified on the original code just to recreate the problem.